# How do you make it so the navbar is transparent then changes color using bootstrap 3. (Affix)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ive been trying to find out how to do this for a week and have been unable to do it. My html navbar looks like this.

```
<div class="maincontainer">
<!--Navbar-->
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" >
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pixoweb</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Examples<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Example 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
    $('#myAffix').affix({
  offset: {
    top: 100,
    bottom: function () {
      return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
    }
  }
})
```

css

```
      .affix {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: #957595 !important;
}
```

So far this has made it so that the navbar goes behind the the context and images. I would like it if someone can help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navbar has not gone behind the text/images, it has been 3d transformed by bootstrap affix so that it looks like it has gone behind. I assume that you want to change the background color of the navbar when it is pinned (affixed). You can use following CSS. Note: you don't need JavaScript.

```
.affix .navbar-default {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: #957595 !important;
}

.affix {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The color changed but for some reason the navbar is still showing up behind the content and pictures. Do you know how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with my menu displaying behind my images, I fixed it by adding "z-index: 1;" to my nav class. eg:.navbar-inverse in the style sheet

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #201f1f;
  border-color: #f47d20;
  border-bottom:#f47d20 5px solid;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```